# Angular module declaration vs. appending everything to the main Module

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a structure for a hybrid app built with ionic.

We use gulp to concat and minify the files.

So far i **append** every controller, service and directive **to my main module** defined in app.js.

Each of these components is defined in its **own file** which are then **concatenated** with gulp with app.js first and everything else last.

This is the way ionic does it for their 10k loc IonicModule.

Is there any reason why i should use the angular module system for more than the main apps module (e.g. **app.directives, app.controllers** etc.) besides the better structure (each component in one file) which i already have with ionics approach?

I could think of two things:

1. **Testability**: as far as i know i don't have to declare a module as *angular.module* , i should be able to mock controller modules (e.g. myApp.controller(x...) as well
2. **Performance**: there shouldn't be a performance gain as far as i know, am i wrong about that?

Comment: I wouldn't imagine performance is an issue but a third consideration would be reusability, making reusable modules like userMananement or whatever will make you just need minor changes in your next project, for several functionality parts.

Comment: May be helpful: https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/27/13-step-guide-angularjs-modularization/

Comment: essentially all i have to do now is change the main modules name if i want to reuse something, so myApp.controller(...) can be reused with myApp2.controller(...)